# How to intercept method execution of inner non-spring class, which is defined in Spring managed bean?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I need to implement interceptor of inner class, outer class is managed by Spring

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Outer {

    protected class Inner {

        protected void methodToIntercept() {
        }

    }

}
```

`Outer.Inner.class` may have childs (anonymous as well). Overriden `methodToIntercept()` should be intercepted as well

Documentation is pretty straightforward:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw

According to documentation I configured everything in following way:

Project structure

```
-src
--main
---java
----temp
-----Config.java
-----MyAspect.java
-----Outer.java
-----SpringBean.java
--test
---resources
----META-INF
-----aop.xml
```

aop.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="temp.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="temp.MyAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@ComponentScan("temp")
@Lazy
public class Config {
}
```

Outer.java

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Outer {

    @Component
    public static class Inner {

        public void methodToIntercept() {
        }

    }

}
```

MyAspect.java

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Autowired
    private SpringBean springBean;

    @Around("execution(* temp.Outer.Inner.methodToIntercept())")
    public Object interceptor(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("success");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

It doesn't work as I expected unfortunately

Should it work with such configuration? What do I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your custom annotation and annotate the method.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ServiceLoggable {
}
```

Your ***@Around*** will look like this

```
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.company.core.log.ServiceLoggable)")
    public Object logServiceMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        ...    
    }
```